# C++ basic converting and then adding up user inputs

Tags: c++, input, error-checking

This is my attempt at a solution I wrote for an exercise in Bjarne Stroustrup's *Programming Principles and C++* book. Unfortunately, the section I wrote to give the total amount of money from the coins entered is not working how I would like!

A quick answer and I would be very grateful but if anyone also has the time could they help me introduce some basic error checking?

The way I would want it to work would be after a user input is required (e.g How many 20p's do you have?), to check whether or not the user inputted an `int`. If not, provide a subtle error message and a chance to repeat the same question, rather than stop the program or start the program from the beginning!

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main() {
int one, ten, twenty, fifty, one_pound, two_pound;
double amount;
amount = (one * 0.01) + (ten * 0.1) + (twenty * 0.2) + (fifty * 0.5) + one_pound + (two_pound * 2);
cout << "Welcome to the change counter app!\nHow many 1p's do you have?\n";
cin >> one;
cout << "How many 10p's do you have?\n";
cin >> ten;
cout << "How many 20p's do you have?\n";
cin >> twenty;
cout << "How many 50p's do you have?\n";
cin >> fifty;
cout << "How many £1 coin's do you have?\n";
cin >> one_pound;
cout << "How many £2 coin's do you have?\n";
cin >> two_pound;
cout << "You have: " << one << " 1p coins!\n"
    << "You have: " << ten << " 2p coins!\n"
    << "You have: " << twenty << " 20p coins!\n"
    << "You have: " << fifty << " 50p coins!\n"
    << "You have: " << one_pound << " £1 coins!\n"
    << "You have: " << two_pound << " £2 coins!\n"
    << "The total amount of money you have is: " << amount << "\n";
}
```

Comment: move `amount = (one * 0.01) + (....` after last `cin` et before last `cout`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I suggest you take a look round the Help Centre, in particular the section on "How to ask a good question".

Answer (score 0):

You have *two* problems:

The first is that in the absence of loops, code runs from top to bottom. That means you calculate `amount` *before* you read the input.

The second problem is that when you calculate `amount` (currently, in the wrong place) you use the variables `one`, `ten`, etc. *before* they are initialized. Uninitialized local variables will have an *indeterminate* value, and using them will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The simple solution to both problems is to move the calculation of `amount` to *after* you have read the input, but *before* you write the output.